# Find kth node from the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I written below function to `find kth node from the end.` However, one hidden test case is failing.
Please let me know what is wrong with below code.

```
def find_kth_from_end(l, k):
    slow = l.head
    fast = l.head
    for _ in range(k):
        fast = fast.next
    
    if fast is None:
        return l.head
        
    while fast.next:
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next
    
    return slow.next
```

```
Error details
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Comment: [mcve], full trace back!!! We have no idea of which variable is set to none.

Comment: In your *for* loop your are unconditionally setting *fast = fast.next* but what if *fast.next is None* ?

Answer (score 0):

That is my solution, but you have to import sys:

```
def find_kth_from_end(list,index):

slow_pointer=fast_pointer=list.head
counter=0
for _ in range(index):
    print("counter Pointer at: ", counter)
    if fast_pointer:
        print("Fast Pointer at: ", fast_pointer.value)
        fast_pointer=fast_pointer.next
        counter+=1
    elif fast_pointer is None and counter<(index-1):
         print("You have inputed a wrong index, you have given 
               extra",(index-counter))
         sys.exit(0)
for _ in range(index):
     if fast_pointer:
         slow_pointer = slow_pointer.next
         fast_pointer=  fast_pointer.next
return slow_pointer
```